# How can I reverse the elements inside the file and return it?

Tags: python, list, function, tuples

So I'm trying to write a function rvrse(fname:str) -> str that reads data from a given filename and returns the reverse of the file content. Your function should ignore the following characters `' ', '\r', '\n', '\t'`.

For example, supposed there is a file called test.txt with the following content:

```
a b c
   d e
 f g

assert rvrse('test.txt') == 'gfedcba'
```

Here is my code so far, which clearly doesn't work....

```
def rvrse(fname):
    content = []
    with open(fname, 'r') as write_reversed:
        for line in write_reversed:
            content.append(line)
    return list(reversed(content))
```

However, this doesn't work... what am I doing wrong??

Comment: why are you returning a list from the function when your assert expects a string?

Comment: Do you want to remove spaces and new line \n from text also?

Answer (score 2):

You are basically reversing the line order, but not the lines itself.

Try this, where you process the whole content as a single block of text.

```
import re


def rvrse(fname):
    with open(fname, 'r') as write_reversed:
        content = write_reversed.read()
    
    # reverse the entire content, replace all unwanted things
    return re.sub(r"\n|\s|\t", "", "".join(reversed(content)))


print(rvrse("test.txt"))
```